# Voltage in circuit (beginner)

Tags: voltage

What is V_O in the following circuit?
[image]

The book I'm reading says it's 2V but I don't understand how.

This is how I see it:
[image]
So V_O from what I know must be less than 2V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The voltage across a resistor is given by Ohm's Law:

$$V = I R$$

In this case, one end of the resistor is an open circuit (it's not connected to anything else). Therefore the current through the resistor is 0 A.

$$0\ \mathrm{A}\times 15\ k\Omega = 0\ \mathrm{V}$$

So the voltage drop across the resistor is 0.

The voltage across a series combination of two elements is the sum of the voltages across the individual elements:
$$2\ \mathrm{V} + 0\ \mathrm{V} = 2\ \mathrm{V}$$

Therefore the voltage \$V_O\$ is 2 V.

If you were to connect any load at all to the output terminals, allowing some current to flow, then your analysis would be correct and the output voltage would drop below 2 V.

Comment: I thought they leave the ends open to say you can add anything you want after it, I never knew it's possible to leave a circuit open. Thanks.

Comment: If the question is "what is the output voltage of the following circuit?", then they are asking about the exact circuit drawn, nothing more and nothing less (even if, like in this case, what's drawn isn't actually a complete circuit). If they wanted you to assume there is some load attached, they'd have to tell you what that load is, or you wouldn't be able to solve the problem.